# Powershell netsh automatically run script

Tags: powershell, scripting, ipv4, netsh

Is there a way to input text to notepad stating an IP Address, Subnet mask and Gateway and then running a powershell script that would execute the following netsh interface ipv4> set address name="Wireless Network Connection" source=static addr=192.xxx.x.xx mask=255.255.0.0 gateway=xxx.xxx.x.x gwmetric=0

At the moment I just type that manually in a Powershell terminal or cmd and it works (changes what i want changed) but i want to be able to just edit a notepad file and exute a batch file that would automatically do it..

i am pretty new to powershell and scripting but if someone can point me in the right direction it would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for you to do this. Here is one:

ip_properties.txt contents:

```
192.168.1.15,255.255.255.0,192.168.1.1
```

powershell script contents:

```
$properties = (Get-Content ip_properties.txt) -split ','
Invoke-Expression "netsh interface ip set address name='Wireless Network Connection' source=static addr=$($properties[0]) mask=$($properties[1]) gateway=$($properties[2]) gwmetric=0"
```

Essentially you're supplying your interface parameters in a comma separated format, splitting the those properties into an array and then using the array elements as inputs to the `netsh` command

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that and it has given me the following error:

'Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Desktop\change.ps1:2 char:18
+ Invoke-Expression <<<<  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand'

Comment: I had made a typo in `Get-Content` so try again, have amended the question. You also don't _have_ to use `Invoke-Expression`, so try just running the string without it